# Reading Azure Blob storage account from Databricks using SAS token

Tags: azure-databricks

I am able to read blob storage account from Databricks using Access keys by below code. However, i am unable to do it using SAS token. Can someone please show me , how can I modify the below code to read the storage account using SAS token?

```
container= 'testcontainer'    
storage_account ='testaccount'
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net", "ABCDEFGHIJKlmnopqrstuvwxyz==")    
access_path = f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/"
dbutils.fs.ls(access_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow below syntax:**

```
spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net","SAS TOKEN")

access_path = "wasbs://<Container_name>@<Storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/"
dbutils.fs.ls(access_path)
```

**Output:**

[image: Ref1]

For more information refer this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage)

**Updated:**

SAS token

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref1]

Comment: I believe vamblob is your storage account name? and are you using the SAS token or the Connection string. can you please confirm_

Comment: i am using SAS Token

Comment: it does not work for me.. its give me error "fs.azure.AzureException: Container testcontainer in account testaccount.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can&#39;t create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration."

Comment: Are you using the question mark in the SAS token?

Comment: and also confirm if you have generated the SAS token at storage account level or at container level?

Comment: no, just updated Please check : )

Comment: didnt get you..what have you updated

Comment: I have generated SAS token at container level, and you check above image

Comment: not working for me..

Comment: Hi @ZZZSharePoint, as per above comment, you are getting same error or different. let me know if you are still having same problem .

Comment: I get the same error as above

Comment: This error happened due to the wrong SAS key configuration which did not have all permissions for the container. provide enough permission to SAS key then only your code will work. and also check whether the Storage blob data contributor was added or not. If not , Go to **Azure Storage Account** -> **Access control (IAM)** -> **+Add role assignment** as `Storage blob data contributor`.

Comment: We should not have question mark in SAS. Remove it if you are using. Also select appropriate permissions while generating SAS. Make sure you are using SAS before expiry.

If you are trying to do same with ADLS gen2 then generate SAS to storage account level.